# Excel formula to return every other column on a sheet, and formula to return last filled row number anywhere in sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for an excel formula that takes an input of an arbitrary number of columns (minimum 4) and outputs every other column, either on the same on on two different sheets. [Here is an example dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7595.png).

I'm also looking for a formula that returns the row number of the last filled cell anywhere in a sheet (not just in one particular row).

Comment: So check if the column number is even, or odd... two functions come to mind; even() and column()

Comment: As already mentioned above, using `ISEVEN` or `ISODD` and with `MOD()` & `COLUMN()` function you could do this: `=LET(α,FILTER(A1:F5,ISEVEN(SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(A1:F1)))),IF(α=0,"",α))` or `=LET(α,FILTER(A1:F5,MOD(COLUMN(A1:F1),2)=1),IF(α=0,"",α))` change the `ISEVEN` to `ISODD` in the first approach to get the other data and or change the `1` for `MOD()` to `0`

Comment: This formula is almost perfect, it just has a fixed input range. I've come up with =INDEX('Sheet 1'!1:1,1,SEQUENCE(1,COUNTA('Sheet 1'!1:1)/2,1,2)) to work with any number of columns, but it only returns the first row and not every containing data

Comment: May be something like this then : **`=LET(α, INDEX(1:6, SEQUENCE( ROWS(1:6) ), SEQUENCE(, MATCH(7^89, 1/(1:1<>"") ) ) ),σ, FILTER(α, ISEVEN( SEQUENCE(, MATCH(7^89, 1/(1:1<>"") ) ) ) ),IF(σ=0,"",σ))`**

Comment: Is it also possible to have a variable number of rows? Presumably the formula would need to be on a different sheet to not include itself in the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula produces the output that matches the OP's data. The input data is in the columns `A:F`.

```
=LET(rng,A:F,
     start,1,
     f,FILTER(rng,BYROW(rng,LAMBDA(r,COUNTA(r)>0))),
     n,SEQUENCE(INT((COLUMNS(f)+1)/2),,start,2),
     x,CHOOSECOLS(f,n),
     IF(LEN(x)>0,x,"")    )
```

Breaking it down into steps:

- `rng` = the input range of columns eg `A:F`
- `start` = the starting column ie `1` or `2`
- `f` = the input range filtering out blank rows
- `n` = the index of every other column, starting from `start`
- `x` = the range `f` with only the columns in `n` selected

The final result replaces any blanks with "".

This also includes the headers in the output. If the headers aren't needed, then replace the first line with `rng,DROP(A:F,1)`.

Comment: I've added an indirect function to define a variable range which includes any number of columns to the first line (also including the function to drop headers) with this formula

 =LET(rng,DROP(INDIRECT("A:"&CHAR(COUNTA($1:$1)+96)),1),
     start,1,
     f,FILTER(rng,BYROW(rng,LAMBDA(r,COUNTA(r)>0))),
     n,SEQUENCE(INT((COLUMNS(f)+1)/2),,start,2),
     x,CHOOSECOLS(f,n),
     IF(LEN(x)>0,x,"")    )

Comment: @AdamW INDIRECT should really be a last resort (the main issue being that it is volatile and will recalculate every time, which will slow down your sheet). Once you have the number of used columns, you can just use a range that is much larger than you will need (eg A:ZZ), and then only TAKE the number of columns you need. eg `DROP(TAKE(A:ZZ,,COUNTA(1:1)),1)`